# Hosting OpenERP on a local server so that other networked computers can access it

Tags: odoo

I want to host OpenERP on a local server so that all the computers on the network would be able to access it via the server. At the moment, I just use localhost:8080 for the server computer. How can I change the ip address so that other computers in the network can access it?

Comment: What is the ip address of the "server" machine? localhost will only work from the server itself, so you'll need to: find the ip address of the server (start > run > cmd > ipconfig if Windows), put the ipaddress:8080 in client machine browser, check local firewall settings, ???, profi-and that should be all.

Comment: I was thinking that there should be a place where I can change the IPs that OpenERP server accepts. Even when I use my IP, it doesn't open it

Comment: Do you know OpenERP by default sets port 8069 not 8080 don't you?